# Why form::text takes up all width of browser viewport and how to make it narrower

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to all
I was creating laravel project and used form::text which I got from laravelcollective.com but in the view the textbox occupies all width of browser viewport and I am wondering how to make it narrower. The code:  `{{Form::text('BrandName', '', ['class'=>'form-control'])}}`

Comment: Add another class, one of yours, and style the field with that

Comment: Or simply `{{Form::text('BrandName', '', ['class'=>'form-control', 'style'=>'width:100px'])}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's full width because of your CSS class `form-control`, it has `width: 100%`.

You can change class

```
{{ Form::text('BrandName', '', ['class' => 'form-control max-width-150']) }}
```

then add CSS

```
.max-width-150 {
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

Or add directly style to your input.

```
{{ Form::text('BrandName', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'max-width: 150px']) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great solution

Answer (score 1):

I suppose from your css classes that you are using Bootstrap. The [`form-control`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_forms.scss#L9) class will always style your component to 100% of the container width.

If you don't want this you will have to add custom css with a custom `width` modifier.

```
.form-control {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great solution

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Bootstrap's grid system and wrap it in a div like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        /* Your form-text code */
    </div>
</div>
```

Vary the number '3' to you taste. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp) for more info.

Comment: @Chukweemeka Inya, Thank you for your great and unusual solution :)